# Celery &Redis:WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?

Tags: redis, celery

I am using celery with redis as a broker. Lately, I see my celery stops working.

```
[2017-10-02 07:06:17,536: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: '' (0b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'binary'
  delivery_info:{'priority': 0, 'routing_key': 'celery', 'exchange': 'celery'} headers={}}
```

I checked in google but found this github issue : https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3675

But this issue seems to be related to rabbitmq. But i am using redis as a broker. Please help me with as i am not able to figure out what is causing the problem. Also, it is not the case that tasks are not getting executed. This happens in 2 or 3 days, hence becoming a very painstaking issue.

Comment: Are the client and the worker using the same celery version?